# Debian installer built with simple-cdd failed to install custom package

Tags: debian, debian-stretch, debian-packaging

First of all, I apologize for my bad english.

I'm trying to create a Debian 9 installer with simple-cdd including my custom package I built myself. I've already been adding custom package that I built with the exactly same process for a long time without any issue, but today I'm facing an issue I can't explain. I don't think the package itselft isn't built correctly because as I said, it's built the same way as working package.

The installer is running well until I get this message : "An attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from the CD failed."
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gis5U.png

This is the error I have in the /var/log/syslog file telling me that one of my package is not installing (and in fact, another one depending on this first, but I think only the first one is revelant) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy0AL.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4nOL.png

When I try to dig a bit more around this error, I can see the package I want to install in the /cdrom/pool/main/m/MyPackage/MyPackage.deb

When I tell the installer to ignore this error, I can finish the installation process but then, I will need to install my package by hand. I still can use the installer drive, and what's more, I can install the package that should have been used during the install process by using :

```
dpkg -i MyPackage.deb
```

The only hint I can guess is that this package is a bit hudge (more than 2GB) and that may be why it's asking for another DVD.

I'm building my iso with this command :

```
build-simple-cdd --conf "MyProfile" --dvd
```

My profile file is as follow :

```
locale=fr_FR
profiles="LogicBox"
simple_cdd_dir=$(pwd)
auto_profiles="MyProfile"
local_packages="$simple_cdd_dir/deb/"
mirror_components="main non-free"
```

And in the MyProfile.preseed file, this parameters may be revelant :

```
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean true
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean true
d-i apt-setup/cd/another boolean false
d-i apt-setup/another boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-first boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-next boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-failed boolean false
```

Last but not least, I'm testing this on VirtualBox 6.1 environment, but I tried also on physical system Intel J1900 / 8G Ram / 256 SSD with no better results.
As a workaround, I'm thinking about putting thoose custom deb files in MyProfile.extra and asking preseed/late-command to install it by hand with an ugly command like :

```
in-target dpkg -i /media/cdrom/simple-cdd/MyPackage.deb
```

Do you have any hint for me to solve this issue ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Sounds like you simply have not generated an up to date package index which includes your package, though I'm not sure if that is the error you would receive for that. Probably try to reduce this to a situation where you have a package index, a package, and an `apt` command which does not work even when you are sure the index is up to date. Perhaps check with `apt-cache policy yourpackage` but this does not sound like a topic for Stack Overflow (maybe delete this and as on our sibling site [unix.se] instead?)

Comment: Why are you targeting Debian 9 anyway? It will EOL in June even for the LTS support.

Comment: @tripleee A bit hard to copy past when it's running within the installer busybox directly. I wrote by hand one of the revelant error message I got. I'll try to copy paste the others by starting the machine when ignoring the message.
For your point, I'm not building the package index by hand. All is done by simple-cdd and the profile (with the local_packages directive I mentioned).
The target Debian 9 is a constraint I have to deal with for now (let's say it's because of my company).
You may be right by redirecting me on Unix & Linux. Thank you for your advice. Can I copy paste on it too ?

Comment: By the way, I think the main problem is somewhere around simple-cdd and the size of the package I'm trying to include. 
As I wrote in the initial post, I've already used the same process to build my iso file without this package and it's working like a charm. I can had / remove other custom package. Only this one is not working.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I suggest trying to reduce to something you can test on your regular computer. Every site here will probably prefer text we can copy/paste because that makes it significantly easier to repro; see the linked message above for details.

Comment: The point is, as I mentioned before, the package can be installed correctly with dpkg -i MyPackage.deb.
The steps are : 
building the iso with build-simple-cdd with the local_package directory
Starting the installation process.
Ignoring the error message
Finishing the install process.
Starting the fresh system
Mounting the iso in the fresh system
Installing the package "by hand" with dpkg. No error